# Capture snapshot taken by iOS when going to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, screenshot, multitasking

Whenever an `**iOS**` application goes to background, the system takes a snapshot of it to present it in the multitask switcher. Is there any chance to get access to this screenshot? I know it corresponds to the top window, and this could be edited from

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

But the results are not the one expected, and would like to know what exactly is iOS snapshotting.

Comment: what you do want to do with captured screen shot ? as I know you can ignore iOS to take and use screen shot by using following method 'ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch'

Comment: @KetanP I am displaying a splash screen, and in some cases the splash is not displayed. I would like to know what screenshot is being taken in that moment.

Comment: you can use Ignore screen shot by method 'ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch' link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW126

Answer (score 0):

use this code to capture snapshot:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> 


if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.window.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);

[self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
if(imgData)
    [imgData writeToFile:@"screenshot.png" atomically:YES];
else
    NSLog(@"error while taking screenshot");
```

Comment: Thanks @prince Where should I place this code? At the end of  `applicationDidEnterBackground:` ?

Comment: You can use the newer `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` on the UIWindow instance instead of `renderInContext` and maybe get better results!

Comment: I am getting `image = nil` with both solutions @prince @AndrewCarter

Comment: are you testing on device or simulator?

Answer (score 0):

In the [App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW8) for iOS, Apple says:

obscuring/replacing sensitive information, you might also want to tell iOS 7 to not take the screen snapshot via ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW126) for this method:

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I do want to take a screenShot, so I don't want to hide it.